# Howto design Tables for Navigating Hierarchical Regions with Diamond Structures

Tags: postgresql, navigation, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

Our solution needs us to work in hierarchies of regions which are as follows.

```
                 STATE
                   |
                DISTRICT
                   |
                 TALUK
                /    \
               /      \
            HOBLI     PANCHAYAT
                \      /     
                 \    /
                  \  /
                VILLAGE
```

There are 2 ways to navigate to a village from a Taluk. Either through HOBLI OR through PANCHAYAT.

We need a PK(non-business KEY) and a SERIAL_NUMBER/ID for each STATE, DISTRICT, TALUK, HOBLI, PANCHAYAT, VILLAGE; However, each village has 8 additional attributes.

How do I design this structure in **PostgreSQL 8.4** ?

My previous experience was on Oracle so I'm wondering how to navigate hierarchical structures in PostgreSQL 8.4 ? If at all, the solution should be friendly for READ/navigation speed.

```
 ================================================================
```

Quassnoi : Here is a sample hierarchy

```
                KARNATAKA
                    |
                    |
              TUMKUR (District)
                    |
                    |
                    |
              KUNIGAL (Taluk)
             /              \
            /                \
           /                  \
      HULIYUR DURGA(Hobli)   CHOWDANAKUPPE(Panchayat)
           \                         /
            \                       /
             \                     /
              \                   /
               \                 /
          Voddarakempapura(Village)
          Ankanahalli(Village)
          Chowdanakuppe(Village)
          Yedehalli(Village)
```

NAVIGATE : For now, I will be presenting 2 separate UI screens each having separate navigable hierarchies

**#1 using HOBLI** and 
So, for #1, I will need the entire tree starting from STATE, DISTRICT(s), TALUK(s), HOBLI(s), VILLAGE(s). Using the above tree, I will need

```
     KARNATAKA (State)
        |
        |
        |---TUMKUR (District)
                 |
                 |
                 |-----KUNIGAL(Taluk)
                                 |
                                 |
                               **|----HULIYUR DURGA(Hobli)**
                                               |
                                               |
                                               |---VODDARAKEMPAPURA(Village)
                                               |
                                               |---Yedehalli(Village)
                                               |
                                               |---Ankanahalli(Village)
```

**#2 using PANCHAYAT**. 
So, for #2, I will need the entire tree starting from STATE, DISTRICT(s), TALUK(s), PANCHAYAT(s), VILLAGE(s)

```
     KARNATAKA (state)
        |
        |
        |---TUMKUR (District)
                 |
                 |
                 |-----KUNIGAL(Taluk)
                                 |
                                 |
                               **|----CHOWDANAKUPPE (Panchayat)**
                                               |
                                               |
                                               |---VODDARAKEMPAPURA(Village)
                                               |
                                               |---Ankanahalli(Village)
                                               |
                                               |---Chowdanakuppe(Village)
```

## ResultSet

Should be able to create above Trees with the following details.
We need a PK(non-business KEY) and a SERIAL_NUMBER/ID for each STATE, DISTRICT, TALUK, HOBLI, PANCHAYAT, VILLAGE along with a Name and LEVEL of the relationship(similar to ORACLE'S *LEVEL*).

For now, getting the above ResultSet is OK. But in the future, we will need an ability to do reporting(some aggregation) at a HOBLI/PANCHAYAT/TALUK level.

=====================================

**@Quassnoi #2**,
Thank you very much,

"If you are planning to add some more hierarchy axes, it may be worth creating a separate table to store the hierarchies (with the axis field added) rather than adding the fields to the table."

Actually, I simplified the existing requirement so as NOT to confuse anyone. The **actual hierarchy** is like this

```
                 STATE
                   |
                DISTRICT
                   |
                 TALUK
                /    \
               /      \
            HOBLI     PANCHAYAT
                \      /     
                 \    /
                  \  /
             REVENUE VILLAGE
                   |
                   |
               HABITATION
```

Sample data for such a hierarchy is like below

```
                KARNATAKA
                    |
              TUMKUR (District)
                    |
              KUNIGAL (Taluk)
             /              \
            /                \
      HULIYUR DURGA(Hobli)   CHOWDANAKUPPE(Panchayat)
             \                     /
              \                   /
               Thavarekere(Revenue Village)
             /                             \
 Bommanahalli(habitation)             Tavarekere(Habitation)
```

Will anything in your solution below change by the above modification ?

Also, would you recommend that I create another Table like below to store the 7 properties of the Habitats ? Is there a better way to store such info ?

```
CREATE TABLE habitatDetails
(
        id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        serialNumber BIGINT NOT NULL,
        habitatid BIGINT NOT NULL, -- we will add these details only for habitats
        CONSTRAINT "habitatdetails_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("habitatid")
           REFERENCES "public"."t_hierarchy"("id")
        prop1 VARCHAR(128) ,
        prop2 VARCHAR(128) ,
        prop3 VARCHAR(128) ,
        prop4 VARCHAR(128) ,
        prop5 VARCHAR(128) ,
        prop6 VARCHAR(128) ,
        prop7 VARCHAR(128) ,
);
```

Thank you,

Comment: What do you mean by "nagivate"? Can a village belong to a `hobli` and a `panchayat` at the same time?

Comment: navigate : for the purpose of presenting it to the USER in a tree like structure, need a SQL(or 2) to get navigate from a DISTRICT to the village using the HOBLI hierarchy or the PANCHAYAT hierarchy.
<br>
yes, a village belongs to a HOBLI(in the REVENUE/TAXES hierarchy) and a village belongs to PANCHAYAT(in the POLITICAL hierarchy) at the same time.

Comment: could you please post some sample data (for one village) and the resultset you'd like to get?

Comment: Quassnoi : thank you. I have modified(appended) the question since the comment did NOT have enough space!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE t_hierarchy
(
        id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        type VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
        tax_parent BIGINT,
        gov_parent BIGINT,
        CHECK (NOT (tax_parent IS NULL AND gov_parent IS NULL))
);

CREATE INDEX ix_hierarchy_taxparent ON t_hierarchy (tax_parent);

CREATE INDEX ix_hierarchy_govparent ON t_hierarchy (gov_parent);

INSERT
INTO    t_hierarchy
VALUES  (1, 'State', 'Karnataka', 0, 0),
        (2, 'District', 'Tumkur', 1, 1),
        (3, 'Taluk', 'Kunigal', 2, 2),
        (4, 'Hobli', 'Huliyur Durga', 3, NULL),
        (5, 'Panchayat', 'Chowdanakuppe', NULL, 3),
        (6, 'Village', 'Voddarakempapura', 4, 5),
        (7, 'Village', 'Ankanahalli', 4, 5),
        (8, 'Village', 'Chowdanakuppe', 4, 5),
        (9, 'Village', 'Yedehalli', 4, 5)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_hierarchy_tax(level INT, start BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE (level INT, h t_hierarchy)
AS
$$
        SELECT  $1, h
        FROM    t_hierarchy h
        WHERE   h.id = $2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  (f).*
        FROM    (
                SELECT  fn_hierarchy_tax($1 + 1, h.id) f
                FROM    t_hierarchy h
                WHERE   h.tax_parent = $2
                ) q;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_hierarchy_tax(start BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE (level INT, h t_hierarchy)
AS
$$
        SELECT  fn_hierarchy_tax(1, $1);
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_hierarchy_gov(level INT, start BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE (level INT, h t_hierarchy)
AS
$$
        SELECT  $1, h
        FROM    t_hierarchy h
        WHERE   h.id = $2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  (f).*
        FROM    (
                SELECT  fn_hierarchy_gov($1 + 1, h.id) f
                FROM    t_hierarchy h
                WHERE   h.gov_parent = $2
                ) q;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_hierarchy_gov(start BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE (level INT, h t_hierarchy)
AS
$$
        SELECT  fn_hierarchy_gov(1, $1);
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';

SELECT  ht.level, (ht.h).*
FROM    fn_hierarchy_tax(1) ht;

SELECT  ht.level, (ht.h).*
FROM    fn_hierarchy_gov(1) ht;
```

The main idea is to keep two parents in two different fields, and use `CONNECT BY` emulation (rather than recursive `CTE`) functionality to preserve the order.

If you are planning to add some more hierarchy axes, it may be worth creating a separate table to store the hierarchies (with the axis field added) rather than adding the fields to the table.

**Update:**

> Will anything in your solution below change by the above modification?

No, it will work alright.

By "axes" I mean hierarchy chains. Currently, you have two axes: political hierarchy (though hablis) and tax hierarchy (through panchayats). If you are planning to add some more axes (which is of course improbable), you may consider storing the hierarchies in another table and adding "axis" field to that table. Again, it's very improbable that you want to do this, I just mentioned this possibility for the other readers who may have a similar problem.

> Also, would you recommend that I create another Table like below to store the 7 properties of the Habitats ? Is there a better way to store such info ?

Yes, keeping them in a separate table is a good idea.

Comment: Quassnoi : Thank you. I will try it out and let you know.

Axes and Fields : Not sure I understand correctly. I have appended a clarification to my question above called Quassnoi #2. Pls let me know if that is what you mean ?

thank you

Comment: I tried to award you the bounty but stackoverflow responded saying that I have 9 more hours before I can do the same.

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted your answer. 2 more hours to go before I grant you the bounty.
<br>
I have asked another clarification of you at Quassnoi #3 above. Can you pls take a look ? Thank you.